# Is that possible? We can implement Apple In-App purchase using HTML script and function?

Tags: html, ios, in-app-purchase, purchase-order

I am using HTML file in my application and there is one anchor tag

```
<html>
...
<a href=""> Get full version of app </a>
...
</html>
```

for purchasing full version.

Is there any possible way to implement In-App purchase in HTML file?

Comment: you may want to check this out : https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 0):

Adding In-app purchases to HTML isn't possible. Assuming that you want the user to purchase the app when the user clicks it, You can have 2 versions of your app, one free(less features) and the other can be paid. If you have followed the MVC pattern well it shouldn't be a lot of work. And then you can link the anchor tag to the paid version of your app